# Android SMS verification APi

Tags: android, android-build-flavors, sms-verification

I have developed app with multiple build flavours like dev, test, prod so when i am using sms verification api, i am able to read sms only in prod mode but not in other mode, i have verified that the hash that is being sent to server is different for different build flavour and server is also sending the same hash in sms which is being send by the app, but the problem is the the sms verification api receiver is able to read the sms for prod build flavour and not for other build flavour.

Build flavour code

```
flavorDimensions "version"

productFlavors {

    gamma {
        dimension "version"
        applicationId "packagename.test"
        versionNameSuffix "-test"
    }

    api2 {
        dimension "version"
        applicationId "packagename.dev"
        versionNameSuffix "-dev"
    }
    prod {
        dimension "version"
        applicationId "packagename"
    }
}
```

code to generate hash

```
   public ArrayList<String> getAppSignatures() {
    ArrayList<String> appSignaturesHashs = new ArrayList<>();
try {
        // Get all package details
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Signature[] signatures = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;

        for (Signature signature : signatures) {
            String hash = hash(packageName, signature.toCharsString());
            if (hash != null) {
                appSignaturesHashs.add(String.format("%s", hash));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Package not found", e);
    }
    return appSignaturesHashs;
}

@TargetApi(19)
private static String hash(String packageName, String signature) {
    String appInfo = packageName + " " + signature;
    try {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_TYPE);
        messageDigest.update(appInfo.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] hashSignature = messageDigest.digest();

        // truncated into NUM_HASHED_BYTES
        hashSignature = Arrays.copyOfRange(hashSignature, 0, NUM_HASHED_BYTES);
        // encode into Base64
        String base64Hash = Base64.encodeToString(hashSignature, Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP);
        base64Hash = base64Hash.substring(0, NUM_BASE64_CHAR);

        return base64Hash;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "No Such Algorithm Exception", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Any suggestion or help would be great.

Comment: You have to include relevant parts of your code, we are unable to help you with the given information

Comment: I think hash is different for debug and release builds so be sure that server is sending correct hashcode for correct flavour and build type(release or debug)

Comment: @ConfusedPup server is sending correct hash in the sms. i have verified it